# Batching within an Apache Spark RDD map

Tags: classification, apache-spark, rdd

I have a situation where an underlying function operates significantly more efficiently when given batches to work on.  I have existing code like this:

```
// subjects: RDD[Subject]
val subjects = Subject.load(job, sparkContext, config)
val classifications = subjects.flatMap(subject => classify(subject)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
classifications.saveAsTextFile(config.output)
```

The `classify` method works on single elements but would be more efficient operating on groups of elements.  I considered using `coalesce` to split the RDD into chunks and acting on each chunk as a group, however there are two problems with this:

1. I'm not sure how to return the mapped RDD.
2. `classify` doesn't know in advance how big the groups should be and it varies based on the contents of the input.

Sample code on how `classify` could be called in an ideal situation (the output is kludgey since it can't spill for very large inputs):

```
def classifyRdd (subjects: RDD[Subject]): RDD[(String, Long)] = {
  val classifier = new Classifier
  subjects.foreach(subject => classifier.classifyInBatches(subject))
  classifier.classifyRemaining
  classifier.results
}
```

This way `classifyInBatches` can have code like this internally:

```
def classifyInBatches(subject: Subject) {
  if (!internals.canAdd(subject)) {
    partialResults.add(internals.processExisting)
  }
  internals.add(subject) // Assumption: at least one will fit.
}
```

What can I do in Apache Spark that will allow behavior somewhat like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `mapPartitions` method, which allows your map function to consume a partition as an iterator and produce an iterator of output.

You should be able to write something like this:

```
subjectsRDD.mapPartitions { subjects =>
  val classifier = new Classifier
  subjects.foreach(subject => classifier.classifyInBatches(subject))
  classifier.classifyRemaining
  classifier.results
}
```

Comment: I assume that `subjectsRDD` could be partitioned into manageable chunks using coalesce?  Or is there a better option?

Comment: Do you want larger or smaller partitions?  `coalesce` decreases the number of partitions in an RDD.  If you want to classify smaller batches, you can either create more partitions in some upstream step, `repartition` subjectsRDD (which I don't recommend because that requires a shuffle), or add a second layer of batching inside of your `mapPartitions` call (e.g. by calling `.grouped()` on the `subjects` iterator).